# Ordering elements from ng-click in an ng-repeat looping

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have  `<span class="sort-max"  ng-click="orderProperty = '-price'">`
and some ng-controller with items. I need sorting when I click on a button, what am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="items-grid" ng-controller="StoreController as store">              
<div class="item" ng-repeat="product in store.products | orderBy : 'orderProperty'">                 
<div class="item-info">
   <p class="item-title">{{ product.name }}</p> 
   <p class="price">{{product.price }}$</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes in

```
ng-repeat="product in store.products | orderBy : 'orderProperty'"
```

so it becomes

```
ng-repeat="product in store.products | orderBy : orderProperty"
```

See this demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Fa34oC7op5M1fWpXkAgg?p=preview

Here is the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="orderByExample1">
<div class="items-grid" ng-controller="StoreController as store">
  <a href="#" class="sort-max" ng-click="orderProperty = '-price'">Sort</a>
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="product in store.products | orderBy : orderProperty">
    <div class="item-info">
      <p class="item-title">{{ product.name }}</p>
      <p class="price">{{product.price }}$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('orderByExample1', [])
  .controller('StoreController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.orderProperty = 'price';
    $scope.store = {};
    $scope.store.products = [
      {name: 'Product A',   price: 10},
      {name: 'Product B',   price: 12},
      {name: 'Product C',   price: 99},
      {name: 'Product D',   price: 23},
    ];
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

Will using `ng-repeat="... | orderBy : 'orderProperty'"`, `orderProperty` is a **string**. You are ordering by a property named  `orderProperty`.

It won't look for a **variable** name `orderProperty`, because you put it between quotes.

---

As `$scope.orderProperty` is set by your button, just removing the quotes may work:

```
ng-repeat="product in store.products | orderBy : orderProperty"
```